# array of UIImageView in objective c

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I already had many UIImageViews..
I want to make an array of UIImageViews and assign every index with one of the UIImageViews above..
How can I do that with objective c??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Declare a NSMutableArray

```
NSMutableArray * imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Simply add the Pointers to ImageViews in the Array E.g: imageView1, imageView2

```
[imagesArray addObjects: imageView1, imageView2, nil];
```

Don't forget to Release the array if you are not using ARC

Comment: thank you Jamal.. But how can I access each element of the array individually??

Comment: I did :).. do u know about accessing the elements??

Comment: Whenever you need to assign some image to an imageView simply do:  UIImageView * imageView = [imagesArray objectAtIndex:Any index];  imageView.image = [UIImage imagedNamed:@"image.png"];

Comment: No such thing as `addObjects: `. There is an `addObject:` for one object

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray * imageViewsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[imageViewsArray addObject:imageView1];
[imageViewsArray addObject:imageView2];

UIImageView * imageView = [imageViewsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

or
    UIImageView * imageView = imageViewsArray[0];